# Why can you read, but not modify, global values?

Tags: python

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
2.4.4
>>> b = 11
>>> def foo2():
...    a = b
...    print a, b
...
>>> foo2()
11 11
>>> def foo3():
...    a = b 
...    b = 12
...    print a, b
...
>>> foo3()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo3
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
>>> def foo4():
...    global b
...    a = b
...    b = 12
...    print a, b
...
>>> foo4()
11 12
```

**Question**> In `foo3`, why you can access global variable without declaring it but you still cannot modify it.

Comment: Because it makes sense this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a `global` declaration, the Python compiler scans the whole code of each function to see which variables are *assigned to* within the function code. In `foo3()`, you assign to both `a` and `b` so therefore they are both treated as local variables within the function.

When the method code executes, at the point where you do `a = b`, `b` does not have a value yet (because you have not assigned anything to it). Therefore, you get an `UnboundLocalError`.

This is done so that the use of a variable within a function *always* refers to the same location, even if nothing has been assigned to it yet.

Comment: So your point is that `foo2` works b/c `b` has not been assigned a value and it is treated as a possible global variable.

Comment: @q0987: Correct.  Python searches local and then global namespaces to read variables.

Answer (score 3):

Accidentally stomping on a global variable is a frequent source of error. So it makes sense to declare a variable `global` before you modify it.

Having to always declare a non-local variable `global` is a pain. So you're allowed to just use a global variable if all you do is read it. But if you're going to modify x anywhere in your function, you must declare it global before you do *anything* with it.

Comment: It's also pertinent to note that using global variables is often (but not always) a bad idea inside functions, partially due to readability and clarity, and accessing/modifying global variables frequently is slower than just using local variables.